# Firebase pagination problem, how to set the latest document reference correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to perform infinite scroll in react component, but after all the data loads latestMealDoc becomes undefined.

Also same thing happens when I go to different route and come back to the component, the latest document is incorrect and I start getting the same items all over again.

Am i setting the state wrong?

```
const [latestMealDoc, setLatestMealDoc] = useContext(latestMealDocContext);

const getNextMeals = async () => {
  const ref = db
    .collection("meals")
    .orderBy("timestamp")
    .limit(6)
    .startAfter(latestMealDoc || 0);
  const data = await ref.get();
  data.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    const meal = doc.data();
    setMealSearchResults((prev: any) => [...prev, meal]);
  });
  setLatestMealDoc(data.docs[data.docs.length - 1]);
};
useEffect(() => {
  getNextMeals();
}, []);
```

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/l11hq3/firebase_pagination_problem_how_to_set_the_latest/

Answer (score 0):

- Can you log the output of `latestMealDoc`?
- What are you expecting to see for `latestMealDoc`?

It sounds like the [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) variable has not been assigned a value yet.

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined. A method or statement also returns undefined if the variable that is being evaluated does not have an assigned value. A function returns undefined if a value was not returned.